# Full name field on node using Display Suite

Tags: display-suite

I am using Display Suite for layout and arrangement of nodes. I would like to display the full name of a node author (a field I have added to the user entity). Display Suite will only show the author username.

How do I display the full name field on a node, instead of the author username?

Comment: Can you edit your question to provide some more info/details, to make your question easier to understand / accurate?

Comment: Is this easier to understand?

Comment: Have you tried real name module?

Comment: I have tried Real Name module and it's not accessible from Display Suite by default. Not sure if you need to code something to bring it in...but coding is not my particular strength.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need a field formatter. You have a few options:

1. Use [Drupal's mechanism](http://www.metaltoad.com/blog/drupal-7-tutorial-creating-custom-formatters) and create one yourself.
2. Use the *[Custom Formatter](https://www.drupal.org/project/custom_formatters)* module to create a custom formatter.
3. Use Display Suite to create a [custom code field](https://www.drupal.org/node/1795314).

If you aren't comfortable with coding, options 2 and 3 are good choices. Option 1 is leaner since if you already have a custom module it wouldn't add the overhead to your site of enabling another module.

Comment: Thanks @merauluka. I will look into the 3 options you mention and see how much goes into each. Coding doesnt come easy to me....but I'll try.